# How can I replace a string in all column headers of a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Python in Databricks on Azure. I've attempted to use *str.replace* but I get an error saying that the column names are not string type. The original file was uploaded as a *parquet* file; I'm not sure if this has something to do with the string error. Any ideas on how to remove the first two characters?

I included an image of the table for reference and an image of the string error.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('T$', '')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: with indexing you_datafram[ 0:2 , : ] it might work

Comment: df_1 = df_1\
    .toDF(*[col[2:] for col in df_1.columns])

This ended up working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$ has a special meaning in str.replace. Best to escape it using a backslash as follows.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('T\$', '')
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error as before: [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str']

Comment: df_1 = df_1\
    .toDF(*[col[2:] for col in df_1.columns])

This ended up working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```py
old_names = df.columns
new_names = [name.replace('T$', '') for name in old_names]
df.rename(columns={old_name: new_name for old_name, new_name in zip(old_names, new_names)}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Getting this error: [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rename']

Comment: df_1 = df_1\
    .toDF(*[col[2:] for col in df_1.columns])

This ended up working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `rename` function was new in pandas version `0.18.0.` What version of pandas are you using?